# "Something went wrong" message trying to authorize with Partner Connections Manager

Tags: nest-device-access

When I load the Partner Connections Manager authorization URL in the browser, I get the following error message:

```
Something Went Wrong
```

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the OAuth Client ID matches between your Device Access project and the Partner Connections Manager (PCM) URL, and that you're using the correct Project ID in the URL.

Go to the Project Info page for your project in the Device Access Console.  Note the Project ID and OAuth Client ID assigned to your project.  Make sure these values match what you're using in the PCM URL.

For example, if the Project ID for your project is `32c4c3bc-fe0d-461b-b51c-f3885afff2f0` and the OAuth Client ID is `90471209828-u96nolblvuk5jv1b22gdfvov4qgbcbhh.apps.googleusercontent.com`, then your PCM URL should look like:

```
https://nestservices.google.com/partnerconnections/32c4c3bc-fe0d-461b-b51c-f3885afff2f0/auth?
  redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&
  access_type=offline&
  prompt=consent&
  client_id=90471209828-u96nolblvuk5jv1b22gdfvov4qgbcbhh.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  response_type=code&
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service
```

For more information, see [Create a Project](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/project/create#create_your_project) and [Authorize an Account](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize) on the Device Access site.